# LWP getstore usage

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm pretty new to Perl. While I just created a simple scripts to retrieve a file with 
`getstore($url, $file);`
But how do I know whether the task is done correctly or the connection interrupted in the middle, or authentication failed, or whatever response.  I searched all the web and I found some, like [a response list](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#DESCRIPTION), and some talking about useragent stuff, which I totally can't understand, especially the operator `$ua->`. 
What I wish is to an explanation about that operator stuff (I don't even know what `->` used for), and the RC code meaning, and finally, how to use it. 
Its a lot of stuff so I appreciate any answer given, even just partially. And, thanks first for whoever will to help. =)

Comment: The documentation says "The return value is the HTTP response code." -  https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::Simple#getstore-url-file - so you could check that?

Comment: "$o->m" is basically call method "m" on object "o". Similar to "." in some languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `LWP::Simple` module is just that: quite simplistic. The documentation states that the `getstore` function returns the HTTP status code which we can save into a variable. There are also the `is_success` and `is_error` functions that tell us whether a certain return value is ok or not.

```
my $url      = "http://www.example.com/";
my $filename = "some-file.html";
my $rc = getstore($url, $filename)
if (is_error($rc)) {
  die "getstore of <$url> failed with $rc";
}
```

Of course, this doesn't catch errors with the file system.

The `die` throws a fatal exception that terminates the execution of your script and displays itself on the terminal. If you don't want to abort execution use `warn`.

The `LWP::Simple` functions provide high-level controls for common tasks. If you need more control over the requests, you have to manually create an `LWP::UserAgent`. An user agent (abbreviated *ua*) is a browser-like object that can make requests to servers. We have very detailed control over these requests, and can even modify the exact header fields.

The `->` operator is a general dereference operator, which you'll use a lot when you need complex data structures. It is also used for *method calls* in object-oriented programming:

```
$object->method(@args);
```

would call the `method` on `$object` with the `@args`. We can also call methods on class names. To create a new object, usually the `new` method is used on the class name:

```
my $object = The::Class->new();
```

Methods are just like functions, except that you leave it to the class of the object to figure out which function exactly will be called.

The normal workflow with `LWP::UserAgent` looks like this:

```
use LWP::UserAgent; # load the class

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
```

We can also provide named arguments to the `new` method. Because these UA objects are robots, it is considered good manners to tell everybody who sent this Bot. We can do so with the `from` field:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
  from => 'ss-tangerine@example.com',
);
```

We could also change the `timeout` from the default three minutes. These options can also be set *after* we constructed a new `$ua`, so we can do

```
$ua->timeout(30);  # half a minute
```

The `$ua` has methods for all the HTTP requests like `get` and `post`. To duplicate the behaviour of `getstore`, we first have to `get` the URL we are interested in:

```
my $url = "http://www.example.com/";

my $response = $ua->get($url);
```

The `$response` is an object too, and we can ask it whether it `is_success`:

```
$response->is_success or die $response->status_line;
```

So if execution flows past this statement, everything went fine. We can now access the content of the request. NB: use the `decoded_content` method, as this manages transfer encodings for us:

```
my $content = $response->decoded_content;
```

We can now print that to a file:

```
use autodie; # automatic error handling
open my $fh, ">", "some-file.html";
print {$fh} $content;
```

(when handling binary files on Windows: `binmode $fh` after opening the file, or use the `">:raw"` open mode)

Done!

To learn about `LWP::UserAgent`, read the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent). To learn about objects, read [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). You can also visit the [perl tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) on SO for some book suggestions.

Comment: Great, thanks for the hard work. I'll keep on doing research on that UserAgent stuff as I actually misunderstood it as a Perl default function instead of a class.
EDIT: should the `use autodie;` placed at the beginning of the source? what does it actually handle?

Comment: @SSTangerine Every script should start with `use strict; use warnings; use autodie;`. The `strict` aborts compilation e.g. when forgetting to declare variables. The `warnings` emits a warning message when you do something dubious, like printing an uninitialized variable. The `autodie` replaces *builtin functions* like `open` or `print` with versions that throw a fatal exception when an error occurs. Otherwise you'd have to check the return value for these functions, which can be tiring. When an error occurs for `open`, this tells you the exact reason and filename, which makes debugging easier.

Comment: See also the [autodie documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/autodie) for the full information, and a list of trapped functions.

Comment: I use strict and warnings by default, but never seen autodie before, seems nice to it.
EDIT: as up above which @asjo mentioned, how can I check the response code?

Comment: @SSTangerine Good :) The `LWP::Simple` module exports constants with names like `RC_OK`. You can then compare numerically: `if ($rc != RC_OK)`. But there are many status codes that would be ok. Therefore, you should use `if (is_error($rc))` or `if(is_success($rc))` as documented [here](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP::Status). Use the status code constants only for fine grained control, e.g. `if ($rc == RC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY)`. PS: I just found [lwptut](https://metacpan.org/module/lwptut) which you may like.

Comment: Understood it.  Last question, I tried my pl with a video clips, sized about 100mb, but the file is corrupted.  Any tips on this? I would like to validate whether the downloaded file is exactly same as the source, without even a byte is different.

Comment: @SSTangerine Are you downloading with `LWP::Simple` or `LWP::UserAgent`? I'd rather use the UserAgent method, to make sure the decoded (uncompressed) content is saved. If you are on Windows, you also have to `binmode $fh` your filehandle before writing a binary file.

Comment: @SSTangerine If you are interested in performance (as that is a large file), you may want to look beyond the LWP libraries. [This talk](https://speakerdeck.com/mrallen1/giving-lwp-its-well-deserved-golden-watch) shows some alternatives.

Comment: i tried out with binmode and everything worked =D
Thanks for your help while you spent so much time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
One question: the following line actually gets the required content in the memory, right?
my $response = $ua->get($url);
What if I wanted to store the contents on the disk using the minimal amount of memory (e.g., when the contents are too large to be stored in memory)? It was my understanding that "getstore" was doing exactly that, right?

Comment: @mike622867 the [implementation of getstore](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.27/lib/LWP/Simple.pm) calls $ua->request($request, $file) and according to [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/libwww-perl-6.27/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#get) "the response content will be saved here instead of in the response object".  Some experiments or source-spelunking should be able to confirm whether this in fact streams to the file or reads it all in and then writes it out.  Left as an exercise for the reader, for now.